# Как задать базовую форму на фронтенде?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, bootstrap

Если собирать `html` с помощью `python`, то всегда можно сделать шаблон, а потом подключить к нему отдельные `html`- вставки через `{% extends "base.html" %}`. Что-то очень похожее есть в `Java` с `jsp`.

Возникает вопрос, можно ли сделать базовый шаблон без участия бэкенд сервера ? Использую `AngularJS` + `Bootstrap 3` + `nginx`.

Comment: Немного не понятна суть вопроса. В моём понимании вы в любом случае должны делать формы на frontend (я использую vue) и в форму передавать данные с backend (использую laravel) или просто получать данные на backend от frontend (в моей ситуации через Request)... Ответ на ваш вопрос, если я все правильно понял, да можно и в принципе даже нужно

Comment: Конечно можно. Angular как и любой MVC-фреймворк предоставляет средства для шаблонизации. Читайте документацию.

Comment: Возможно это поможет решить проблему http://taoofcode.net/creating-a-plugin-system-with-the-compile-provider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

шаблонизатор, который собирает шаблон в `python` (да и в php) называется [twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/). Он очень мощный и лаконичный. В нём можно подключать определённые блоки, делать свои расширения, наследовать шаблоны, шаблоны шаблонов ...  Вообщем он достаточно мощный.

В ангуларе механизм наследования шаблонов другой. 
Там это достигается за счёт директив, и гнездования роутов.

Один из примеров наследования шаблонов в ангуляре.

Так же возможно вставка других шаблонов с помощью [include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude).

Один из примеров создания [директив](https://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/FHVD9/)

Механизм гнездования роутинга можно почитать в этой [статье](https://habrahabr.ru/post/190096/)

Comment: Ещё нужно напомнить что там же, эээ, обитают компоненты, которые собираются в маленькие, эээ, стаи и спариваются создавая великолепные, эээ, композиции.

Comment: "да и в php", ваш кругозор остановился на одном шаблонизаторе?

Comment: @OlmerDale при чём тут компоненты к первому ангулару? Этот механизм был расширен уже позже большей частью для миграции на второй ангулар

Comment: @OlegShleif нет, ещё использовал smarty. Просто twig более гибкий и удобный.

Comment: @OlegShleif я сделал вывод что это twig по его синтаксису. И twig, в отличии от smarty, используется в python

Comment: да я к слову о компонентах, хотел лишь Вас, орнитологов поддержать. Гнездование роутеров, стрекотание дериктив и миграция в южные сервера, это же из орнитологии?

Comment: @OlmerDale да я понял сарказм. Возможно  мой ответ  напоминает Вам Дроздова, но всё таки быть  полным орнитологом Ангулара мне ещё рано :)

Comment: Вы пропустили ссылку на Один из примеров наследования шаблонов в ангуляре.

Comment: @faoxis вы про angular.extend ?